# C# Graphics Invalidate

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I think I have miss understand the Invalidate method...I am trying to draw a square with the top left hand corner of the square at the location of the mouse at mousedown and then the bottom right hand corner is the current location of the mouse. Below is the method triggered on the MouseMove event. The parent is a panel with a pictureBox child. (I am trying to draw on top of these.)

The problem seems to be with `pictureBoxMain.Invalidate()`. When commented out the code behaves as expected and draws a gazillion squares.

[The Graphics `g` is created by the pictureBox, hence why I call the Invalidate method on the pictureBox.]

When I un-comment out the invalidate line then a box is draw as the mouse moves but as soon as it stops moving the box disappears. I can't work out for the life of me why. When I attempt to debug the code it appears that MouseMove method is being invoked in when the mouse isn't moving, which doesn't make any sense.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
private void pictureBoxMain_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MouseDrawLeft)
        {
            //Move
        }
        else if (MouseDrawRight)
        {
            MouseLast = e.Location;
            if (MouseFirst != MouseLast)
            {
                pictureBoxMain.Invalidate();

                Point bl = new Point(MouseFirst.X, MouseLast.Y);
                Point tr = new Point(MouseLast.X, MouseFirst.Y);

                g.DrawLine(pen, MouseFirst, tr);
                g.DrawLine(pen, MouseFirst, bl);
                g.DrawLine(pen, bl, MouseLast);
                g.DrawLine(pen, tr, MouseLast);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Every component (button, textbox, window...) has its Paint method. This is invoked periodically by Windows (like 50x per second) to draw the object.

What you do is that you paint something on the object - but within a milisecond, it disappears, because the Paint method overpainted it. You need to override the Paint method of the frame and do you paintings there - this way, you drawings will be painted every time Windows ask.

Comment: An example would be helpful here. You want the OP to learn something about how windows paints, show an example override for `OnPaint()`.